# Apache/Adobe Flex Display PDF

Tags: flash, apache-flex, pdf, actionscript

I wanted to know, if recent Apache Flex release have included a new way of displaying PDFs while also controlling the functionality like making the controlbar visible/invisible or add/remove controlbar elements. In the days of Adobe Flex 4.6 you could only display PDF within an HTMLLoader but you can NOT remove the controlbars there.

I also want to add, that all the available libs on the web are not made for instant-load and display (you either have to convert the pdf to swf or change code within pdf).

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF functionality is provided by Adobe AIR, not by the Flex framework, and there is currently no alternatives to using the HTMLLoader. It relies on the PDF support by the system (i.e. Adobe Reader), so the only way to control its behavior from Flash would be to use [PDF Open Parameters](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf). You can hide the control bar with the following command:

```
http://www.example.com/file.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0
```